# Integer.toString() gives incorrect conversion

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the Integer 0550 to a String, but using

```
Integer.toString(0550);
```

gives me the String "360" instead of "0550" which is what I want. I'm confused as to why it is giving me a completely unrelated (or so it seems) String.

Comment: Same reason `System.out.println(0550);` outputs "360". Because octal 550 is decimal 360.

Answer (score 6):

0550 is interpreted as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) by Java.

Try removing the leading zero.

**Further Reading**
[Literals in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

The number `0550` is the octal representation for `360` decimal.

Pass in the radix (8) to get `"550"` literally.

```
Integer.toString(0550, 8);
```

---

### Edit

The JVM does not have the ability to detect if you placed a `0` (octal) or an `x` (hexadecimal) in front of an integer value. So you will not be able to print that out. You need to tell the program that you are expecting input to be octal or hex.

```
public class DisplayInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayInteger(0550);
        displayInteger(550);
    }

    private static void displayInteger(int value) {
        System.out.println("Actual  : " + value);
        System.out.println("Base  8 : " + formatAxOctal(value));
        System.out.println("Base 10 : " + formatAsDecimal(value));
        System.out.println("Base 16 : " + formatAsHex(value) + System.lineSeparator());
    }

    private static String formatAxOctal(int value) {
        return formatInteger(value, 8, "0");
    }

    private static String formatAsDecimal(int value) {
        return formatInteger(value, 10, "");
    }

    private static String formatAsHex(int value) {
        return formatInteger(value, 16, "0x");
    }

    private static String formatInteger(int value, int radix, String prefix) {
        return String.format("%s%s", prefix, Integer.toString(value, radix));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Actual  : 360
Base  8 : 0550
Base 10 : 360
Base 16 : 0x168

Actual  : 550
Base  8 : 01046
Base 10 : 550
Base 16 : 0x226
```

Comment: @Thilo I corrected my mistake. I was thinking of parsing, not formatting...

Comment: But this will be very confusing for other numbers now: `Integer.toString(1000, 8)` will not say "1000".

Comment: @Thilo The precondition is that the number starts with a zero. But this may hard to detect, unless you to-string it and check for a leading zero.

Comment: There is no need to detect anything at runtime. We are talking about compile-time integer literals.  Included in your source code. Just don't start them with a `0`.